# Approaching to this layout, no way to recreate it from the design:

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, xml-layout

thank you in advance for your time:
I'm trying to recreate the design you can see below into an Android Project.

Desired design:

[image]

I tried the next XML code but when I change the screen resolution (Nexus 5 to other) the all thing blows up:

`

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="09dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="ALDONZA"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="VIÑEDOS"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="LA BODEGA"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="NUESTROS VINOS"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="ALDONZA PLACES"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

`

Image of the problem when changing the virtual device:

[image]
Any help?

Comment: in android to supports multiple screens you need to have multiple dimension folder for every type of device

Comment: Do you mean that I have to do a different XML for each screen size?

Comment: by default you have one values folder. but for support multiple screen you need to create multiple values folder. read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html